# Korean cheerleaders

Tags: vocabulary, single-word-request

I notice that at Korean sporting events, groups of fans will set a called cheer. So, what happens is a girl shouts out in cadence and calls for a cheer, then the fan group answers altogether with a cheer.

What is the cheer leader girl called?

EXAMPLE:

At 6:05 of the following video, you can hear examples of the cheers. First you hear the cheer for the first contestant ("Jin Air FIGHTING !!!"), then a second similar cheer is given by the fans of the opposing team ("SKT FIGHTING !!!").

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njxx0yCNqv8

Comment: I assume you're referring to baseball. You need to clarify: Is the "girl" just another fan in the crowd seat, or a professional cheerleader on the mini-stage?

Comment: @MujjinGun It's any sport. Have you been to a sporting event in Korea? What happens is that a girl shouts out as loud as she can "RED DEVILS FIGHT-ING !" Then the whole fan section for that team (or player if it is a solo sport) answers her, shouting at the top of their voice "RED DEVILS FIGHT-ING !!!!"

Comment: I have been to almost every kind of sporting event in Korea, and every one of them have different cheering cultures. What you're describing sounds like soccer, not "any sport". Also you've still not clarified where that "girl" belongs to.

Comment: Any videos of this phenomenon? It seems like we're a bit confused as to what you mean! (oh...and - why was this originally tagged 'joke'?)

Comment: @topomorto I have added a video link. The cheer occurs at 6:05 in the link.

Comment: I see what you mean. This happens a lot in UK soccer but I must admit I'm not sure what we'd call this in English, other than "the person who starts the chant"...

Comment: @topomorto I am asking if there is a specific Korean term for this role?

Comment: @TylerDurden Sure.... I'm just saying I don't even know the English term, so not one I can answer I'm afraid!

Answer (score 3):

The cheer you've described is called 선창(先唱) -- literally a "leading call."

> 진에어 하나 둘 셋!
>
> 진에어 화이팅!

[Quick googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%EC%84%A0%EC%B0%BD%20%22%ED%95%98%EB%82%98%20%EB%91%98%20%EC%85%8B%22%20%ED%99%94%EC%9D%B4%ED%8C%85) gives me two kinds of usage. Properly speaking, only the first line ("진에어 하나 둘 셋!") should be called the 선창 and the latter ("진에어 화이팅!") the 후창(後唱), the "following call." But colloquially, both lines altogether could be called 선창 or 선창 응원 by some.

For the one who did the 선창, I don't think there is a term especially for the role. But probably I would call her 선창 하셨던 분 ("the one who did the leading call") or just 선창.